# Asynchronous API calls using PHP

Tags: php, asynchronous

I have a PHP application that fetches prices from various sources. On every execution, it's loading from over 20 API endpoints using Guzzle. Due to the load time of each call, it's taking 10-30 sec per execution cycle. If I can make all the calls in parallel, I can cut it down to less than 5 seconds.

What's the easiest way to make parallel API calls in PHP?

Comment: http://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/batching/batching.html

Comment: If at all possible you should really fetch the data in the background periodically and keep it cached on your server, so you don't need to make 20 API calls on user request in the first place.

Comment: @deceze I am caching the prices but the TTL is 10 sec as I need it to be up to date.

Comment: how about Threads? http://php.net/manual/de/intro.pthreads.php

Answer (score 3):

You're probably doing the wrong thing. These requests should probably be made at a regular interval in the background and the data be cached.

What you're trying to do is possible by leveraging non-blocking I/O. Curl offers this with `curl_multi`, which is available in Guzzle. But there are also other libraries implementing HTTP clients based on non-blocking I/O without a dependency on `ext-curl`, such as [Artax](https://amphp.org/artax/).

Artax is based on Amp, which provides the basic primitives like the event loop and promises. You can start multiple requests and then wait for the set of promises.

```
$client = new Amp\Artax\DefaultClient;
$promises = [];

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $promises[$url] = Amp\call(function () use ($client, $url) {
        // "yield" inside a coroutine awaits the resolution of the promise
        // returned from Client::request(). The generator is then continued.
        $response = yield $client->request($url);

        // Same for the body here. Yielding an Amp\ByteStream\Message
        // buffers the entire message.
        $body = yield $response->getBody();

        return $body;
    });
}

$responses = Amp\Promise\wait(Amp\Promise\all($promises));
```

Comment: Any recommendations on how to run the requests in the background? The data I need will need to be updated every few seconds and cron only supports as low as one minute.

Comment: @JCLee: You could write a daemon based on Amp that schedules a timer every few seconds. If your information needs to be up-to-date but is only requested infrequently, it's not worth it.

Comment: @kelunik , all these libraries modify the http client. i am using a heavy library which is doing synchronous call with c_url (libray called CCXT https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt ). I dont want to fork this library and change their http call. I am currently trying to find a way to achieve asynchronous call of instance of this library. Am i right to thing it is possible with Amp? Do i need to achieve a custom promise?

Comment: @kelunik For the context : the purpose is to call more than 50 different API endpoints in same time. What is the right direction to investigate?thks for help...

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert the API calls to be done using commands, for example:
If you have 20 calls,

`exec('php apiCall_1.php >> "./log.txt" &')
exec('php apiCall_2.php >> "./log.txt" &')
.
.
.
.
exec('php apiCall_20.php >> "./log.txt" &')`

Notes:

1- All of those commands will be fired in async (do not forget to add the '&' at the end of each command to fire it, so it will not wait for the response).

2- Each command normally will store the result(which is fetched from the server) in DB collection/table.

3- Along with that, you have to write a method that keeps looking for the result if it's inserted to DB or not, so you can take it and send it back to your api consumer.